# How to change the colour of the button glow on a UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm looking to change the colour of the glow on a UINavigationBar. At the moment, it glows black when I tap on a button. How can I change this glow to white?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can
You can change property highlight...